Get Video Thumbnail Image Asynchronously in SwiftUI with Xcode 16
public func getVideoThumbnailImage(url: URL) -> Image {
let urlAsset = AVURLAsset(url: url, options: nil)
let assetImageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: urlAsset)
assetImageGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
assetImageGenerator.apertureMode = .encodedPixels

let cmTime = CMTime(seconds: 1, preferredTimescale: 60)
var thumbnailCGImage: CGImage?
var errorOccurred = false

let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)

assetImageGenerator.generateCGImageAsynchronously(for: cmTime) { generatedImage, timeGenerated, error in
    if error == nil {
        if let cgVideoImage = generatedImage {
            thumbnailCGImage = cgVideoImage
        } else {
            errorOccurred = true
        }
    } else {
        errorOccurred = true
    }
    semaphore.signal()
    return
}

_ = semaphore.wait(timeout: .now() + 30)

if errorOccurred {
    return Image("ImageUnavailable")
}

if let thumbnailImage = thumbnailCGImage {
    let uiImage = UIImage(cgImage: thumbnailImage)
    return Image(uiImage: uiImage)
}

return Image("ImageUnavailable")

}
I am using Xcode 16 beta 2 for iOS 18 with SwiftUI.
My code above works instantly and correctly; however, Xcode produces the purple warning: "Thread running at User-interactive quality-of-service class waiting on a lower QoS thread running at Default quality-of-service class. Investigate ways to avoid priority inversions"
How can I change the code to avoid the purple warning?

Forget about semaphores and start using the Swift Concurrency
func getImage(url: URL) async throws -> Image {
    let urlAsset = AVURLAsset(url: url, options: nil)
    let assetImageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: urlAsset)
    assetImageGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
    assetImageGenerator.apertureMode = .encodedPixels

    let cmTime = CMTime(seconds: 1, preferredTimescale: 60)
    let (image, time) = try await assetImageGenerator.image(at: cmTime)
    
    return Image(uiImage: .init(cgImage: image))
}


Your suggested approach removed the purple warning, but did not get the video thumbnail image resulting in "ImageUnavailable".

@OsmanBalci there is no ImageUnavailable with my approach, you either get an image or an error. If you get an error you can debug with the actual error by catching it in a do/try/catch
